# Is it a problem if a user posts "many" self answered questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, self-answer

So I am sure it is not malicious but figured I would bring it up anyways. I recently noticed a certain user having a large amount of self answered questions in their reputation. The answers themselves are worth answers in my opinion but doesn't this sort of go against the idea of the site of helping others? I do know it is allowed, but wanted to see if anyone has thoughts on to how many are too many, if at all?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: *"doesn't this sort of go against the idea of the site of helping others"* - This is not the main idea of this site. The main idea is to build a knowledge database with question and their answers. Helping others with their question is just a way to build that database. Writing your own answer to your own question is just another way.

Comment: How is it _not_ helping others to increase the sum of useful knowledge easily found on the internet?

Answer (score 15):

If they're low quality questions, or low quality answers, then it's a problem, and you should treat the situation exactly the same as any other time where you see a user with a pattern of providing low quality questions or answers, whether they're self answered or not.

If they're quality contributions, both in the questions and the answers, then the more the better.

> doesn't this sort of go against the idea of the site of helping others

The idea of the site is to create a useful repository of knowledge.  Not to help one person find an answer to their question.  If the questions are creating a useful resource that's likely to be helpful to other people searching for answers to the same question, then that's in line with the site's goals.

Comment: My thought was that a user can just go on some wiki, think of a random question, then provide a random answer on this site which may not be a "good" question but simply something to boost their reputation. I guess the decision if a question is "good" is subjective though

Comment: @EricF If you think that the question isn't a good question, there are tools available to you to indicate as much.  You can downvote it, vote to close it (if merited), etc.  If you feel that the answer is not useful, you can likewise indicate as much through votes on it as well.  This is no different for a self answered question than it would be for a question that *wasn't* self answered.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

> The answers themselves are worth answers in my opinion.

If the answers are worthy answers keep him busy with doing such things again and again by supporting him.

He spend his time to convert his knowledge in a QA format and posted here to help others.

> will go against the idea of the site of helping others

### No

people will benefit from this. Now or in future.

He made a QA post because he has to go through the situation. People in future, if go through the same situation, it will be very helpful for them.

### In short

If they are good question and answer, try to **encourage him to do so more and more**